# Change encoding of text file using Stream class object

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I am using `UploadCsv` method of `BigQuery` Client class. This class accepts `Stream` class object. Can I change encoding of my file and pass this file to stream object without converting my text file to `ByteArray`? I'm using a large file and in case of `ByteArray` it gives out of memory exception.

```
UploadCsvAsync(string datasetId, string tableId, TableSchema schema, Stream input, UploadCsvOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to change the encoding of your *input*. This is because the [UploadCSVAsync](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/api/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClient.html#Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_BigQueryClient_UploadCsvAsync_System_String_System_String_Google_Apis_Bigquery_v2_Data_TableSchema_System_IO_Stream_Google_Cloud_BigQuery_V2_UploadCsvOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) requires the input to be a **System.IO.Stream** class.

This class is the abstract base class of all streams in C#. A stream, on the other hand is a *sequence of bytes*, such as a file, input/output devices, an inter-process communication pipe or a TCP/IP socket. If you changed the type or encoding of the input, it might not match with the [System.IO.Stream remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

This covers the main question "If it possible to change the encoding?", the answer is No.

Now, the next you may ask should be: "If it is not possible, then what do we need to do?", and that's a great question!

For that particular matter, the `Out of memory Exception` Error message can be solved by changing the way we are reading the data. Having a single loop statement to read a single file might not be the best option due to the allocated memory.

Instead, use a buffer to read data as they did [on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24142142/7674214) or use smaller arrays or *jagged arrays* as done on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4815501/7674214).

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: If you are still having issues with the _Out of memory_ Exception, I would recommend to create a new question to focus on it